# Combining two Teradata SQL queries

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm wanting to combine the following two queries into a single query. Here are the two queries. Anyone know if this is possible? The aggregation in the second query makes me think no, but I thought I'd throw it out there to the experts to see your thoughts.

Query 1:

```
SELECT  a.id, a.ord_nb, a.scr,
        a.fr,
        a.rank,
        CASE WHEN tp.tps_jnr_cn > 0 THEN 'Jnrs'
        WHEN tp.tps_chld_cn > 0 THEN 'Chld'
        WHEN tp.tps_ifnt_cn > 0 THEN 'Ifnt'
        WHEN tp.tps_snr_cn > 0 THEN 'Snrs'
        ELSE 'Non'
        END AS Party_Seg,
        CASE WHEN gx.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        AS rpt
FROM    xi.aff a
LEFT JOIN oper.d_tps tp
    ON tp.tps_id = a.ord_nb
LEFT JOIN XI.gst_exprnc gx
    ON a.id = gx.id
    AND tp.strt_dt > gx.strt_dts + INTERVAL '30' DAY
    AND gx.exprnc_typ_id IN (309) --Park Experience
QUALIFY Row_Number() Over (
PARTITION BY ord_nb, scr, fr 
ORDER BY rank DESC) = 1
ORDER BY ord_nb, fr, scr
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT  a.ord_nb,
        a.fr, Max(a.rank), Min(a.rank),
        Max(a.rank) - Min(a.rank)
FROM    (
    SELECT  ord_nb, fr, rank 
    FROM    xi.aff
    QUALIFY Row_Number() Over (
    PARTITION BY ord_nb, fr, scr
    ORDER BY rank DESC) = 1
        ) a
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY ord_nb, fr
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "combine"? Adding the columns from the 2nd qurey to the 1st?

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining both queries as derived tables:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Min_Rank, t2.Max_Rank, t2.Max_Min_Diff_Rank
FROM
  ([--INSERT 1ST QUERY REMOVING ORDER BY AT END--]) t1
INNER JOIN
  ([--INSERT 2ND QUERY REMOVING ORDER BY AT END AND NAMING RANK COLUMNS--]) t2
ON t1.ord_nb = t2.ord_nbAND t2.fr = t2.fr
ORDER BY t1.ord_nb, t1.fr, t1.scr
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Syntax error, expected something like an 'UDFCALLNAME' keywork between '.' and the 'Min' keyword."

Comment: Currently, you do not give aliases to your `MIN()`, and `MAX()` aggregate columns in second query. Try naming them as *Min_Rank*, *Max_Rank*, *Max_Min_Diff_Rank* as I tried commenting in code.